# When to do indexing in lucene

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, lucene

I have REST service which works with data from database (mongodb). I want to add apache lucene library to implement full text search.

I never used Lucene before so trying to understand how it works be checking tutorials, but still one thing is unclear for me:

When to do indexing of DB data? I have DB, some data is added and removed more often, some is updated rarely. What should be structure that I could do search requests by all up to date data.

Should I update indexes on every data update, or it will be done automatically, and enough to index once? If reindexing should be made, so how often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want live data to be searched then you should `add, update and delete` data in lucene index at the same time you perform `add, update and delete` data in your database.

It will perfectly fine just for `indexing` but do not `optimize` your index for every operation.

You can optimize your index once in a day or according to your use. Optimizing index will help you for faster search result.

Refer this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_quick_guide.htm) to just begin with basic application of lucene.

Answer (score 1):

You can try MongoDBs own Feature for this (see [Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/)). This has probably not the flexibility and is not as mighty as Lucene, but it Comes for free.

You really asked the problematic question: "When do indexing?". And the answer depends heavy on your requirements. However, you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988066/mongodb-apache-lucene) to see how it is technically done: offline, i.e. you will always be more or less behind in indexing.